# Radius of covergence

Tags: calculus

Consider the following power series $\sum \frac{x^{2n}}{n!} $  how do we find the radius of convergence? I have only ever seen $ x^{n}$ not $x^{2n}$ so im not sure if the process is still the same. That is we take the limit of $\frac{(n+1)!}{n!}$ then go from there or if the power of x makes us reconsider what we should take the limit of.

Comment: Isn't this just $e^{x^2}$?

Comment: to recognize that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n x^n$ is an entire function (that the radius of convergence is $\infty$) you have to prove that $\frac{1}{n!} = o(a^{-n})$ for every $a$. here $c_{2n+1} =0, c_{2n} = \frac{1}{n!}$... of course, if $f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n x^n$ has radius of convergence $R$ i.e. converges iff $|z| < R$, then $f(z^k) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n x^{kn}$ converges iff $|z^k| < R$ i.e. iff $|z| < R^{1/k}$ hence its radius of convergence is $R^{1/k}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apply the ratio test:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{\frac{x^{2(n+1)}}{(n+1)!}}{\frac{x^{2n}}{n!}}\right|=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{x^{2(n+1)}n!}{x^{2n}(n+1)!}\right|=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{x^2}{n+1}\right|.$$

What restrictions need to be put on $x$ to get this limit to be strictly less than one?

Comment: Would we solve to get x must be less than the square root of n^2 + n?

Comment: Not, quite. The task is to find a constant $M$ so that if $|x|<M$, then the limit is less than 1. The largest value of $M$ so that this is true is the radius of convergence. If course, there might not be any largest value of $M$ that makes it true, in which case the radius in infinite.

Answer (score 0):

Evaluate $|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}|$ find the value of x for which the series is convergent. Note for convergence$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}|<1$$